# Extract subarray of elements that appear after the last occurrence of "4"

Tags: java, array

I am doing some challenges, and in one challenge given a non-empty array of `int`, I am to return a new array containing the elements from the original array that come after the last 4 in the original array. The original array will contain at least one 4.

E.g:

> post4([2, 4, 1, 2]) → [1, 2]
>   post4([4, 1, 4, 2]) → [2]
>   post4([4, 4, 1, 2, 3]) → [1, 2, 3]

As such, I have written code that works but it is far too complicated and unprofessional, at least it feels this way.

```
public static int[] post4(int[] nums) {

    int startPoint = nums.length - 1;
    int[] newArray;
    int amtOfElements = 0;
    int stopIndex = 0;

    for (int i = startPoint; i >= 0; i--) {

        if (nums[i] == 4) {
            stopIndex = i;
            i = 0;
        } else {
            amtOfElements++;
        }
    }

    newArray = new int[amtOfElements];

    for (int i = 0, j = stopIndex; i < amtOfElements; i++, j++) {
        newArray[i] = nums[j + 1];
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

As such, this looks nasty to me.
How can I shorten this to a single `for-loop`?

Comment: Consider looping from the right hand side downward... and stopping when you run into a 4.

Comment: @user3137702  Umm... `for(int i = startPoint;i>=0; i--)`

Comment: My code already does that?

Comment: Personally, I would `break` instead of `i=0;`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll do that for future code @cricket_007 .

Comment: This code seems optimal runtime O(N). Optimal code isn't always short, nor do I think a single loop is possible (because you need to switch direction).

Comment: The thing is I just noticed this description under the challenge section: "Medium difficulty array problems -- 1 loop" which is why I looked at my code more insecurely. They do not provide any solutions / further description past that so I'm left unsure(and like you I can't think of how a single loop could cover this).

Comment: What libraries can you use?

Comment: They don't mention anything about what libraries you can use(otherwise I would've used an arraylist and have it add values until it reaches a 4). But maybe that's the only way you can have one loop. 

If it helps, the site is codingbat.com/

Comment: I was thinking array.copy to dynamically increment array size as you add new data.

Comment: I just went to the site. They accepted the answer below. That is the answer I was getting to. I just needed to know if using Array.copy was acceptable.

Comment: Minor optimizations: `i = 0;` → `break;` and move `amtOfElements++;` out of `else`-block, which is unnecessary here, because once you entered to `if`-block, you break the loop, otherwise you increment `amtOfElements`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use this:

```
public int[] post4(int[] arr) {
  for(int i = arr.length-1; i >= 0; --i) {
    if(arr[i] == 4) {
      return Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, i+1, arr.length);
    }
  }
  return new int[0]; // or null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Stack` data structure based solution:

```
public int[] post4(int[] nums) {

    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
    int i = nums.length - 1;

    while (nums[i] != 4) {
        stack.add(nums[i--]);
    }

    int[] newArray = new int[stack.size()];
    int j = 0;

    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        newArray[j++] = stack.pop();
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

Two very simple and elegant loops with minimum work with indexes.

Answer (score 0):

If you like streams and lambdas (and shorten your code to 0 for loops :), you may use this

```
public static int[] post4(int[] nums) {

    int marker = 4;
    return IntStream.range(0, nums.length) //iterate over the indexes to find the marker
                    .map(i -> nums.length - i - 1) //reverse the order to start from the back
                    .filter(i -> marker == nums[i]) //find the marker
                    .mapToObj(skip -> IntStream.of(nums).skip(skip+1).toArray()) //skip the first elements and the marker (+1)
                    .findFirst() //the new array
                    .orElse(nums); //the original array if there is no marker, or int[0]  - its not that clear from your question
}
```

(although it's actually not shorter than the shortest answer)

Comment: `while` is the simplest way to shorten your code to zero `for`-loops :-)

Comment: :) ... streams are good for avoiding _any_ loops ;)

Comment: I see at least 4 loops, behind the stream methods...

Comment: of course there is, deep down in the reference pipeline, but it doesn't matter what's behind. there's tons of assembler behind that, but all the higher languages are there to _avoid_ writing assembler. And at some other level, nobody really cares whether there are streams or loops behind `post4()` ;)